# Android VideoView error 1,-1004 on Android 2.x

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mp4, 3gp

I'm trying to play a remote video (.mp4) from my server in a VideoView. All works fine on my HTC One S (4.1.1) but as soon as I try it on a Android 2.x device i'm getting a message that the video can not be played, in LogCat is see Error 1, -1004. I also sees Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side.

Off course i Google the error en found out has something to do with not being able to read the file. I've made sure i have INTERNET permission set in my manifest, I also know the file is available for it works on my One S. So my only option is the codec which cannot be read by a earlier Android device. So I tried converting it with Adobe Media Encoder, I've converted it to a bunch of different settings including 3GPP but no success.

Does anybody have any experience with converting video files for Android and making it work on Android 2.x?

Cheers
Daan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says Android Started Support for Live Streaming from Android 3.0 
Refer this : 
http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

Comment: But I don't think i'm using HLS, it's just a .mp4 file that is sitting on a server.

Comment: You are trying to play a file from server. How can it not be HLS. Are you downloading file and playing it from there ?

Comment: I'm playing my video like this: `mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mBaseUrl + mActiveProject.getMovie()));mVideoView.requestFocus();mVideoView.start();` Is it always HLS when using http? I thought your server had to implement HLS...

Comment: Yes it is HLS. Video View is smart enough to play it from URL. Like we have traditional online mp3 player.